# Importing PHP variables into Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

This question may have already been answered, but how can I import variables from PHP into a segment of Javascript in HTML? I have the following PHP variables (these are parameters passed into a PHP script):

```
  $user = $GET[user];
  $pass = $GET[pass];
```

And I am trying to access these variables with the following references in my Javascript code:

```
  var user = "<?=$user?>";
  var pass = "<?=$pass?>";
```

However, when I check the values of these variables with console.log I get the following result:

```
  user = 
  pass =
```

Where am I slipping up? It seems like I just can't read these variables from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple bugs:

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
         ^----^----^--- missing


var user = "<?=$user?>";
            ^^^^^^^^^^---nasty and can break JS.
```

Never dump arbitrary text from PHP into a JS code block. One single JS metacharacter and you've introduced a syntax error and the entire JS block is killed. Always use json_encode():

```
var user = <?= json_encode($user) ?>;
```

Comment: Sorry had $HTTP_GET_VARS rather than $GET... was looking at an old version of my code.

Comment: I've tried using the following code:

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$user = $GET[user];
$pass = $GET[pass];
```

To:

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];
```